# Why always prefix type property requirement with the static keyword in Swift protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols

On page 369 of the book *The Swift Programming Language*, it says **“Always prefix type property requirements with the static keyword when you define them in a protocol.”**

Example Code:

```
protocol AnotherProtocol {
    static var someTypeProperty: Int { get set }
}
```

What is the reason or benefit of doing so?

Comment: Link to the same section in online docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Comment: as opposed to what alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because without the `static` keyword you end up declaring an instance property rather than a type property. The example that immediately follows the paragraph you quote shows this:

> Here’s an example of a protocol with a single instance property requirement:
>
> ```
> protocol FullyNamed {
>     var fullName: String { get }
> }
> ```

Comment: I wasn't able to discern instance property from type property. Now it's clear!

Comment: Is type property just another name for static or class properties?